# having some Error on GridDB Server while query

Tags: griddb

I am experiencing a error on my GridDB server and need assistance in resolving it. The error is occurring when I try to perform certain operations on the server, such as querying or updating data. I have a code that demonstrates the issue, but I'm unsure how to resolve it.

```
GridStoreFactory factory = GridStoreFactory.getInstance();
GridStore gridStore = factory.getGridStore("yourGridStoreConfig");

// Perform an operation on the GridDB server
try {
    // Open a container
    ContainerInfo containerInfo = new ContainerInfo();
    Container container = gridStore.putContainer("labdata", containerInfo, false);

    // Execute a query
    String query = "SELECT * FROM (labdata)";
    RowSet<Row> rowSet = container.query(query);

    // Iterate through the rows
    while (rowSet.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowSet.next();
        // Perform some operation on the row
        // ...
    }

    // Close the container
    container.close();
} catch (GSException e) {
    System.err.println("Error on GridDB server: " + e.getMessage());
}

// Close the GridDB connection
gridStore.close();
```

Comment: What is the error (string or number)? Without any further information this question is not answerable.

Comment: In my thinking, the data mapping with container is the issue, I am looking for the perfect example in which we can extract and load data into some resulted file.